# Thymeleaf th:replace bug?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a layout.html which contains a footer part:

```
<footer th:fragment="site-footer">
&copy; Spring MVC Blog System, 2016
</footer>
```

I want it to my index.html as replacement:

```
  <div th:replace="layout :: site-footer"></div>
```

It should be really simple, but i still run into exception, and i have no clue why.

LOG: http://pastebin.com/ULDJJciu

[image]

Comment: `Exception processing template "index": Exception parsing document: template="layout", line 2 - column 16 (index:12)` have you seen this, what is at line 2 - column 16 of layout.html

Comment: paste your template code from `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` line.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turned out, its not about the 'th:replace', it has problem with the

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

part, the '  "  ' sign is UTF8 in my code and i should have used ASCII. ( happens offen if the source code copied from a website. )

Comment: did your IDE highlight it?

Answer (score 0):

use xmlns as

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

it worked for me